# How to add a list with results selected from input?

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I have a modal with a list and some options. These are getting from database. I need to make a list / input with what I selected in that modal. Can I make that?

Here is my list :

```
    <section> 
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="populerNameKeyOrg" placeholder="Search for contacts" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 38%">
              <label class="select">
                 @if(isset($replyMessage))
                   @foreach($users->contact as $user)
                         <ul id="destPopulerOrg">
                     <li class="countryOrg"><input name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "selected"; } } ?>><span>{{ $user->username }}</span></li>
                             <ul>
                         @endforeach
                 @endif
               </label>
            </section>
```

Every input has an own id ( user id ) like here `<input name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="548">`. So, I need to make something like an Input with that values ( usernames ) selected in my modal.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct solution is here:

**My li:**

```
<li class="country">  <input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "selected"; } } ?>><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">{{ $user->username }}</span></li>
```

**Div for results**

```
Checked users: <div id="results"></div>
```

**Scripts**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

function displayCheckbox() {

    var checkboxes = $(".my_div");
    var results = $("#results");

    $.each(checkboxes, function() {
      $(this).change(printChecked);
    })

    function printChecked() {
        var checkedIds = [];

        checkboxes.each(function() {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                checkedIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });

        console.log(results);
        results.text(checkedIds);
    }
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```html
 <section> 
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="populerNameKeyOrg" placeholder="Search for contacts" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 38%">
    <label class="select">
       @if(isset($replyMessage))
        @foreach($users->contact as $user)
          <ul id="destPopulerOrg">
           <li class="countryOrg"><input name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "checked"; } } ?>><span>{{ $user->username }}</span></li>

          <ul>
         @endforeach
        @endif
    </label>
</section>
```

by the way, make sure to replace `selected` to `checked`

Comment: thank you, but seems that doesn't working :( https://imgur.com/a/UjJFVmr

Comment: Oh, that input is for searching. I need to make a separate input for that :) So that input is for searching which is working. I need to make a new input.

Comment: Go back to your code and try to write `checked` instead of  `selected` @Andrew